# Pre-order printing data from tree data

Tags: c#, printing

So, I have a tree data structure which should work fine but now I want to print the results. My problem is if the parent node has two children (right and left) which aren't null; what path should it take? If it takes lets say right then all of the left ones after that node get left out?

**I want the tree to be in the correct order**

Example of what it'll do if I do not order it correctly:

```
-----------------------------root---------------------------------------
-------------------value---------------skips this value-----------------
-------------value-------skips this value-- skips this value -- skips this value
----------value -------skips this value----- skips this value ---- skips this value
```

What I'd like it to do:

```
-----------------------------------root----------------------------------

---------------------------value-----------value-------------------------
----------------------value----value-----value---value-------------------
--------------------value--value--value-value-value-value-value
```

and so on(I'd continue on but it gets cluttered)

I'll need to place my nodes into a stack and order them in advance. Suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443695/traversing-a-tree-of-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: @DavidBrabant That doesn't resolve my problem

Comment: Your problem is tree traversal problem. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: Why not @user3245390?

Comment: @anonymous So should I make this method traverse like addNode method?

Comment: @rene does the op not explain my issue clearly (genuine question)? The link he posted is for just printing the childs, not printing them under the correct parent and so on

Comment: Assuming your binary tree is correctly structured, to print things in-order you need to implement an inorder traversal. The wiki page even has both recursive and iterative pseudo code on how to perform inorder traversal.

Comment: @user3245390 For me you don't. If you add a couple of nodes as an example, curent output and expected output it would help me to understand.

Comment: @rene Updated the OP, it doesn't look too great but I'm not sure how to draw it with text..

Comment: @anonymous Thank you v much, I'll check the wiki out now!

Comment: @user3245390 you'll get an upvote from me for creativity

Comment: @rene You should see my original print method. It's v similar to the example I put in the OP. (the - are replaced with tabs, and it's centered to begin with). @ everyone I read the wiki and I think recursion would be the only way to do this gonna write some pseudo code and see if I can come up with anything. Bumping this thread as pointers towards the correct direction would be nice. If OP needs updating lemme know  peeps!